# Using XStreamMarshaller , how to display the value of the tag without the name of the tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm trying to marshall an xml document to the following form:

```
<Description language="FR">ceci</Description>
<Description language="AN">this</Description>
```

But I'm getting the following output:

```
<Description language="FR">
    <value>ceci</value>
</Description> 
<Description language="AN">
    </value>this</value>
</Description>
```

Here is the code what I tried:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Description", propOrder = {"value"})
public class Description {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "language", required = true)
    protected Language language;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(Language value) {
        this.language = value;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I expect:
            <Description language="FR">ceci</Description>
            <Description language="AN">this</Description>
            
  actual:
            <Description language="FR">
               <value>ceci</value>
            </Description>
            <Description language="AN">
               </value>this</value>
            </Description>

Answer (score 0):

try with this,

Description.java

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Description", propOrder = {"value"})
public class Description {

    @XmlValue
    protected String value;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "language", required = true)
    protected String language;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String value) {
        this.language = value;
    }
}
```

marshalling with jaxb

```
File outputFile = new File("output path/fileName.xml");
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Description.class);
Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

Description description = new Description();
description.setLanguage("FR");
description.setValue("ceci");

jaxbMarshaller.marshal(description, outputFile);
```

output (fileName.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<description language="FR">ceci</description>
```